# On touching uppermost div selects contents of div under it - z-index property

Tags: javascript, html, css, snap.js

I have a strange problem though, when i click the content with z-index 20, the thing with z-index 1 gets selected in my phone.

The image has both the screen shot - the part on the right side of the image is only for illustrating my problem, as such the white gray div is behind my content div.

Can someone please rescue.

Related CSS files:

```
#content {
background: #000000;
background: url(../img/WireFrame_test.png) center center no-repeat;
box-shadow: 0 0 15px 15px #222222;
overflow-x: hidden;
z-index: 20;
}

.snapjs-right .snap-drawer-right {
    display: block;
    z-index: 10;
}

.snapjs-right .snap-drawer-left {
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
    z-index: 1;

}
```

As requested related HTML scripts:

```
<body>
<div class="snap-drawers" id="leftid">

...

<div class="snap-drawer snap-drawer-right overthrow">
<div>
<h3>Questions</h3>
<div class="demo-social">
</div>
<h4>Java</h4>
<ul>
<li><a href="noDrag.html">What is Java?</a></li>
<li><a href="noDrag.html">Uses of Inheritence?</a></li>

...

</div>
</div>
<div id="content" class="snap-content">
my content goes here

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add the HTML too?

Answer (score 0):

Surely because "Uses of inheritance" is the only link element (other than "What is java"), it will be selected - there's nothing else to select!

Try setting the display of that element to "none" when it is hidden.

Comment: Do you mean to say that if I place some clickable element or something in the #content div (the black div) it will not select ? apparently it does :(

Comment: Interesting... Have you tried setting the css to "display: none" when you don't want it to be clickable?

Comment: Making it invisible will surely solve the problem, but it brings a mild flicker while I attempt to open the content. Actually I am still hoping for some CSS solution that would do the magic. I cannot see any issue when using chrome or likewise in a desktop. The problem is prominent in touch based phones, where the default browser highlights the links/clickables etc., upon touch. I want to disable that in my app.

Comment: Hmm well I'm sorry I can't really be more help - I don't have much experience working with touch-screen phones

Comment: Thanks barnaby - If you know any forum or sites other than stackoverflw where I may get the answers ???

Comment: Not really I'm afraid, just do lots of googling!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to hook into the event when clicking / dragging on the content panel and do an `event.stopPropagation();` or an `event.preventDefault();` when the panel is closed.
As far as i know, you can see that coz Snap.js add's corresponding classes like (**class="snapjs-right"** or **class="snapjs-left"**) to the body in order to indicate if a panel is open or not.

So first you've got to check that.

With jQuery it would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#UsesofInheritence_Anchor_ID").bind("click", function() {
        if (!($('body').hasClass("snapjs-right"))){
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```